# how to fetch array of objects from json

Tags: json, reactjs

This is the api http://skunkworks.ignitesol.com:8000/books/ ,
I am trying to fetch the array results from it using the fetch method but instead get an error cannot fetch value of undefined

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      books: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://skunkworks.ignitesol.com:8000/books/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ books: data }))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        return e;
      });
  }

  render() {
    let book = []
    book = this.state.books.results;
    console.log(book[0])
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Books</h1>
      </div>
    )

  }
}
export default App;
```

this is my code.

Also I have observed that json data are usually like [{}] but here it is {} format.
please suggest me some solution.....

Comment: Looks like you need to run a loop over the results data. The data from what I see inside of the result section is actually json data. The url call is pulling more than just that data. 

I'm not that familiar with reactjs but looks like you might need to do something like a loop to get the data out into individual json objects.

Comment: here is a basic sample fetching data and manipulate it, I suggest you look at this quick tutorial,https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your url link, you json array of data is present in the *results* key of the returned object from the API.

So if you're only interested by the results you should do something like that :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    books: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const objectFromUrl = await fetch('http://skunkworks.ignitesol.com:8000/books/')
    const data = await objectFromUrl.json() //first way
    // or you can use destructuring way 
    const { results } = await objectFromUrl.json() //second way
    this.setState({
      books: data.results // results key contains your '[{}]' data an array of objects
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { books } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Books</h1>
        {books.map(book => (
          <h2> {book.id} </h2>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }

  // You can use destructuring again to get only key you're interested by

  render() {
    const { books } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Books</h1>
        {books.map(({id, formats}) => (
          <h2> {id} </h2>
           <h2> { formats[ˋapplication/pdf’] } </h2>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes now i can fetch results array but how do i fetch the object formats from results.

Comment: You have to iterate over your books array as I did in the render method and extract the formats for each book. I’ve edited my answer

Comment: but it displays only id

Comment: It’s because you have to create html tag to display it. In my answer I display « application/pdf » but you can replace by any key of formats object

Comment: Tell me the displaying result you would like I will edit my answer in consequence

Comment: Thank you so much bro every thing is working fine salute to all those who personally come over stack overflow and solve the problems..........